Converting a Matrix into a list with ALL values
I have a Matrix that has row names & header names that I am trying to convert into a list. Is there a formula that could do this? I have tried a few options but can't wrap my head around how to explain the problem. So please see the picture for clarity.
I am trying to take the matrix and convert to a list that I can script into the system.


Just search for "unpivot".  This question has been asked and answered dozens of times.

A Basic Unpivot
=LET(table,A1:D5,
    h,TAKE(table,1),
    d,DROP(table,1),
    srl,TAKE(d,,1),
    scl,DROP(h,,1),
    sv,DROP(d,,1),
    drl,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(scl)),srl)),
    dcl,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(srl)),scl)),
    dv,TOCOL(sv),
    r,HSTACK(drl,dcl,dv),
    r)


Replace the bottom-most r with any other variable to see what it holds.


After removing the redundant variables h, sv, and r:
=LET(table,A1:D5,
    d,DROP(table,1),
    srl,TAKE(d,,1),
    scl,DROP(TAKE(table,1),,1),
    drl,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(scl)),srl)),
    dcl,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(srl)),scl)),
    dv,TOCOL(DROP(d,,1)),
    HSTACK(drl,dcl,dv))

Further removing the variables drl, dcl, and dv:
=LET(table,A1:D5,
    d,DROP(table,1),
    srl,TAKE(d,,1),
    scl,DROP(TAKE(table,1),,1),
    HSTACK(TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(scl)),srl)),
        TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(srl)),scl)),
        TOCOL(DROP(d,,1))))

or the same:
=LET(
    table,A1:D5,
    d,DROP(table,1),
    srl,TAKE(d,,1),
    scl,DROP(TAKE(table,1),,1),
    HSTACK(
        TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(scl)),srl)),
        TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(srl)),scl)),
        TOCOL(DROP(d,,1))
    )
)

